# Do I need to learn how to build web services to get a iOS / Android developer job?

Tags: android, ios, ios5

I know every iOS job is different. But if you are a iOS/Android developer, have you ever had to deal with creating a web service or did someone else in your team take care of it?

I know my way around in calling web services from an iOS app, but I know nothing about creating a web service. I just want to know if that's a hurdle in a getting a iOS developer job.

I'm sorry to ask such a vague question, but I am just to overwhelmed by all the required skills for getting a iOS developer job. I will avoid asking such questions in the future.

Comment: I think that'll vary by employer, and I really don't think it's on-topic for this site.  That said, there are dozens of ways to "make a web service", and it's a good skill to have.  SOA is becoming more and more prevalent, and the service is where the business logic is at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the size, but I would say companies that aren't startups should have their own team for web services. This also depends if the company is iOS only or if they have a web/android/other products that already utilize an API.

You should definitely check out Ray Wenderlich's tutorials on Web Services here: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

and he also just posted a new tutorial about creating a instagram like web service today.

Most companies aren't going to use PHP as their service so be familiar with different languages, the most common being: java, python and ruby.

Comment: That is a very good link. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In today's software development environment I find that both as an employee and employer that opportunities and compensation go to those with broad expertise.  Great breadth does not have to mean limited depth - specialize in areas that you find the most interesting (and most profitable), but always keep your eyes and ears open to both new technologies and "what the guy in the next cube" is doing.

You don't *have* to learn how to write a web service to use one (it is a service, after all), but learning how to write them is going to help both in your usage of services as well as make you more appealing in the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

If you can program iOS you can program in PHP or any other web language needed to create a web service.

Today the term "web service" is a bit misleading. It used to mean that you use SOAP to implement it. But generally today, a web service is any web page that returns results that your application (or some application) knows how to parse/understand.

Many people are using JSON as the "payload" for web services today, so learning how to send JSON from iOS and parse a JSON result might be helpful. Then you can learn the basics of parsing a JSON request in PHP and creating a JSON result.

To answer your question, it is critical at least to be able to call a web service (and process the response) from iOS. I would also say, that to show you can do that, you should be able to create a basic PHP page that acts as the server for your web service. Do a simple hello world web service in PHP and invoke it from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know how to create them at an expert level, but you do need to know how to work with them. Creating apps, you will interface with web services, and depending on the type of apps you are creating, may have to develop web services. Having an understanding of them won't hurt your chances, but may not be required. It all depends on how the company is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Most apps, games aside, are pulling down content from the web. You certainly need to know how to consume these services. In general, you'll be better at consuming them if you also know how to write the backend.

Most importantly, you want as little logic as possible in your app. Push all the logic to the backend. To do this effectively, you'll need to be working on the front and backend at the same time rather than building the API beforehand. I would follow the REST principles outlined in the [REST in Practice](http://restinpractice.com/book/) book.